# Copies of QSqlQuery share the same bound values

Tags: c++, sql, qt

When I try to copy prepared `QSqlQuery` with assign or copy constructor and bind to them different values with `bindValue` they both will have the same bound value, one which was bound last. Is it the case of implicit sharing? Though this class is not listed as implicitly shared. I wasn't able to find anything in docs. What should I do to make independent copies of a query? I'm using Qt 5.13.2.
Here is the test code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "test");
db.setDatabaseName("text.sqlite3");
db.open();
QSqlQuery createQuery(db);
createQuery.exec("CREATE TABLE if not exists test"
                                      "(test_id integer)");
QSqlQuery query1(db);
query1.prepare("INSERT INTO test (test_id) VALUES(:test_id)");
query1.bindValue(":test_id", 1);
qDebug() << query1.boundValue(":test_id"); //this returns 1
QSqlQuery query2(query1); //the same with QSqlQuery query2 = query1;
query2.bindValue(":test_id", 2);
qDebug() << query1.boundValue(":test_id") << query2.boundValue(":test_id"); //both return 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug, I was [suggested](https://forum.qt.io/topic/124689/copies-of-qsqlquery-share-the-same-bound-values) to report it, which I [did](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-91766). For now it is suggested to use two distinct queries and prepare both.